# Entropy x Complexity - Shannon x Kolmogorov

Tags: entropy, communication-complexity

This is a very common question but I think I’m posting it in a different way.

Suppose that we have 256 different possible messages with uniform distribution to be represented in a binary code. Then it would be necessary at least 8 bits in each word to represent all the $256 = 2^8$ possibilities.  Nevertheless, some of those words may be compressed in fewer than 8 bits. For example, 00000000 may be compressed in log(8) + O(1) bits, and as O(1) becomes asymptotically irrelevant, occurrences of 00000000 can be asymmptotically represented in nearly log(8)=3 bitsspelling. This in obvious contradiction with the minimum of 8 bits required for this codification and, in fact, violates the prefix-code requirement, as this 3 bits compressed word is a prefix for other words in the codification.

My question is how we can bring together both notions of entropy and complexity in dealing with the above situation, as they seem contradictory.

EDIT: I think the answer to my question is this.  If we compress any word in the code to obtain a shorter string, it will become a prefix to other words in the code. So we have to use bigger strings in the place of the non-compressed words to keep the prefix free property. But because the source distribution is uniform, this new word length distribution is not the most efficient, the average length achieved will be above Shannon entropy lower bound, and there’s no contradiction between minimum code length and the possibility to compress strings in the code. Kolmogorov compression is useful for compressing particular strings, but it can’t compress strings in a manner that the average code length is below the source entropy.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by 256 = 28? It must have something to do with $28 = \binom{8}{2}$ and $256 = 2^8$ but I don't see the precise connection.

Comment: In order to communicate a stream of data packets, each of which could be 8 bits _or less_, one may need slightly more than 8 bits per packet, either for whitespace characters or for a length variable, in order to separate the packets from each other.  Otherwisethedatastreamlookslikethisandambiguitiesmayoccur.

Comment: Icannothelplaughingwiththetongueincheekmessageabove...

Comment: I think the apparent contradiction comes from trying to apply asymptotic results to the case $n = 8$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction. How many strings can be uniquely represented by less than $k$ bits? It's at most $1+2+\cdots+2^{k-1}<2^k$ strings (using the empty string as well).

So out of $2^n$ strings of length $n,$ less than $2^{n-t}$ (i.e., less than a fraction $2^{-t}$) can be represented by less than $n-t$ bits and since Shannon entropy gives a lower bound to the average length of codewords, there is no contradiction here.